# Get HourGlass Style in progress in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm currently developing an application in which I want to show progress while using AsyncTask.
I already know about progressbar and progress dialog. But I'd like an hour glass appearance on it. Is there any way to get such an appearance on progress? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In layout Use ProgressBar tag  and download hourglass icon

Here i have taken hourglass_icon.png  and keep that icon in res/drawable folder.

:indeterminateDrawable attribute is used to change icons

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/anim_progress_icon" />
```

Here we are using animation to rotate the hourglass icon

res/drawable/anim_progress_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/hourglass_icon"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />

That's how we can get the hour glass appearance on progress.
```